# Backing up remote Ubuntu VPS via rsync — is it possible and reasonable? Any alternatives?

Tags: backup, vps, rsync, remote-access

I have a VPS on Digitalocean. They do provide 2 ways of backup (snapshots and "regular backups"), but neither of them can be downloaded from them.

My goal is to find a reasonably universal way to back up everything at once. (including system files/settings, etc.)

I have 1 idea currently — to download everything via rsync. With a command like this:

```
rsync -aHz --exclude=swapfile root@MY_HOST_ADDRESS:/ SOME_LOCAL_FOLDER
```

I think, `root` should have read access to all stuff, right?

Am I missing something critical with this approach? And what could be a better way?

NB: The server is running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-62-generic x86_64)

My home computer is running OS X, although it's not a problem to use a VM with whatever OS and software, as long as it's free.

#### Update

the idea does not work in practice, even if I exclude folders like `/proc, /boot, /mnt, /sys, /dev` — after restoring the backup to new droplet it's no longer able to correctly boot.

Comment: Can you access the backups from the VPS (to extract only one file from the backup, which might be a reasonable question to ask the provider)? Maybe via a local ftp connection or something? if so, you can download via the VPS.

Comment: From what I understand (or guess), the backups done by Digitalocean are external to the VPS. Something like "Snapshot" feature in VirtualBox, for example. I do not know why are they not letting the customers download them…

Comment: how do you plan to restore your databases once you retrieve all your files from the server?

Comment: @user4668401 I think, revert to a "clean installation" of that Ubuntu version and then use rsync to overwrite all differing files with the files from the backup

Comment: I am not using any DBs which do raw disk access (ignoring file system)

Comment: your theory would be easy to test, simply deploy another  "clean installation"  (as you describe) droplet - which takes about 1minute - ssh into the new instance and run your `rsync` command - pulling your existing droplet onto the new one  -  you would know in a few minutes whether it worked or not - did you try that?

Comment: @user4668401 creating another droplet is not free, unfortunately. But I think I'll try it on a local VM. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: lol, I thought I was cheap. <https://www.digitalocean.com/pricing> How am I billed?

Each droplet is billed per hour up to its monthly cap.
Do I have to pay the cost of the server every time I create a new one?

No — you only need to pay for 1 hour of usage. Spinning up a new 512MB server just to test something for a couple of minutes will only cost you $0.0074

Comment: oops, didn't know that. then I will definitely try it soon!

Comment: I tried. After doing this, the system is not bootable… :D

Comment: How does the original VM boot? For example using the GRUB bootloader or direct kernel boot (pygrub, pvgrub...)? How do you perform the rsync recovery? If may be that you have to reinstall the bootloader but the specific vary depending upon the approach. Also rsync alone will not give you a point in time snapshot which may or may not be an issue for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you thought but doing this a different way ? Use a [configuration management](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) system to do the system configuration and then just backup the user data ?

Doing it this way allows you to quickly deploy consistent VMs and reduces the size of your backups.

Once you are only backing up user data then rsync is a good tool to use.

Comment: Yes, that's also an option in theory, but (if I understood correctly) I'd have to pay for more RAM. (because running a VM is additional overhead)

Comment: I don't think you have the faintest clue what you are talking about.

Comment: sure, that's hard to understand if I never heard about `configuration management software` (although I did use Vagrant and know what it does). I'll try to read and understand something…